# Problem with linking flask and PostgreSQL. Error message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'

Tags: python, flask, psql

Code of import.py file is given below which is used to display entries of flights.csv file:

```
    import csv
    import os

    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

    engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
    db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

    def main():
        f = open("flights.csv")
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        for origin, destination, duration in reader:

            db.execute("INSERT INTO flights (origin, destination, duration) 
            VALUES (:origin, :destination, :duration)",
            {"origin": origin, "destination": destination, "duration": 
            duration})

            print(f"Added flight from {origin} to {destination} lasting 
            {duration} minutes.")

        db.commit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

}

[Image shows the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONa5d.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. You can read a good explanation of why this makes it difficult to help you here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3801865

Comment: Also please format your traceback as code since this is almost impossible to read

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to know what the problem is. Have you definitely defined your DATABASE_URL ? `export DATABASE_URL="http://my_url.com"` in terminal (for mac/linux) inside your virtual environment will define it for you. If you could add some information on what you have tried to do, that might help.

Comment: Well, that's the problem I guess. I don't know what to place in "DATABASE_URL". It will be helpful if you can share a link/video or something that properly shows how to link PostgreSQL with Flask because I did not find something useful on the net.

Comment: OK. Here is how you could set up a PostgreSQL database online, hosted on Heroku.

1. Navigate to https://www.heroku.com/, and create an account if you don’t already have one.
2. On Heroku’s Dashboard, click “New” and choose “Create new app.”
3.Give your app a name, and click “Create app.”
4.On your app’s “Overview” page, click the “Configure Add-ons” button.
5.In the “Add-ons” section of the page, type in and select “Heroku Postgres.”

Comment: 6.Choose the “Hobby Dev - Free” plan, which will give you access to a free PostgreSQL database that will support up to 10,000 rows of data. Click “Provision.”
7.Now, click the “Heroku Postgres :: Database” link.
8.You should now be on your database’s overview page. Click on “Settings”, and then “View Credentials.” This is the information you’ll need to log into your database.

Comment: If you have installed psql. you can run the command `psql url` where url is the url you got in the credentials settings of your heroku database.